# Web application not connecting to Oracle 11g R2

Tags: tomcat, oracle11g

I have a web application running fine on oracle 9i with tomcat, when I want to upgrade I have installed Oracle 11g release 2 and JDK 7 and apache tomcat7 on Windows 7 64bit machine to check the compatibility before installing it on my machine.

I have created dsn and test connect successful, installed ojdbc6, ucp, orai18n in `oralce11g/jdbc/lib` as well as in tomcat lib folders, still my application using jdbcodbc driver is not connecting to the Oracle 11gR2 database.

Please guide me step by step as I am new to tomcat and oracle 11g as well.

Comment: I have solved it my self, i have added only ojdbc6 to rtomcat lib, the error is earlier i have added ojdbc6_g, ora18n, ojdbc5, ojdbc6dms, ojdbc14 also. I have removed all added files except ojdbc6 and after it is working fine ... any how thanks for this platform

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it my self, i have added only ojdbc6 to rtomcat lib, 
the error is earlier i have added ojdbc6_g, ora18n, ojdbc5, ojdbc6dms, ojdbc14 also. 
I have removed all added files except ojdbc6.
Now it is working fine ... any how thanks for this platform